# update click once package without visual studio

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, deployment, clickonce

I have click once application which works fine when deployed/published through VS 2010. 
But I have a requirement when my app require some file changes or updated after its been deployed. So I want every client who installed the app gets updated files and I don’t want to use VS for this.

To achieve the same I am using mageUI.exe. So for example my file structure is like this:

```
MyAppIISFolder
   Web.xml
   MyApp.application
   Setup.exe
   Application Files(folder)
          MyAppVersion(folder)
               Some.dll.deploy
               MyApp.exe.manifest
               myApp.application
               fileToChange.txt.deploy
```

Following steps I followed to achieve the same:

1. I replaced file “fileToChange.txt.deploy” with updated file named “”fileToChange.txt”.
2. After that I open mageUI.exe
3. Open file “MyAppIISFolder\Application Files\ MyAppVersion\ MyApp.exe.manifest”

   ```
   a.  Went to “Files” tab and clicked on populate. 
   b.  Got Following error message MyApp.application.deploy found with deploy extension. Overwrite? 
   c.  I clicked “Yes”
   d.  The Went to “Name” tab and increased the version number
   e.  Saved the file and selected new sign certificate
   ```
4. No from mageUI.exe I opened file “MyAppIISFolder\Application Files\ MyAppVersion\MyApp.application”
       a.  Went to “Application Reference”
       b.  Selected updated manifest and saved with new sign certificate
5. Opened file “MyAppIISFolder\MyApp.application”

   ```
   a.  Went to “Application Reference” tab
   b.  Selected Manifest and saved the file
   c.  Gone to “Name” folder and updated the version number
   ```

Now when one of the installed client try to update itself I got the following error:

```
ERROR SUMMARY
Below is a summary of the errors, details of these errors are listed later in the log.
* Activation of C:\Users\me\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\MyApp\MyApp.appref-ms| resulted in exception. Following failure messages were detected:
    + Exception reading manifest from 
  http://me/ MyAppIISFolder/Application%20Files/ MyAppVersion /MyApp.exe.manifest: the manifest may not be valid or the file could not be opened.
    + Parsing and DOM creation of the manifest resulted in error. Following parsing errors were noticed: 
        -HRESULT:   0x80070c81
         Start line:    0
         Start column:  0
         Host file:     
    + Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070C81
```

I think, i am missing out a step or two which is causing this error. thr are very less blogs about mageUI.exe so could not found something relevant to it....

Comment: how did you deploy this app in the first place? Have you tried using msbuild.exe to build the app from the command line?

Comment: I am deploying the app through Visual studio 2010 only. Not using msbuild.exe